# Wordpress Plugin Keeps using the old version of a .php file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

This is my first try creating a WordPress plugin to do an import of data from a mysql database. PHP isn't my strongest suit either, but I created this plug in and went to enable it and it complained about an error on line `123` (literally).  Sure enough there was, I forgot the `$` on a property of a class.  Fine, I fixed it, and then delete the plugin because it didn't start, install the new one, now my menu item showed up, cool, so now I clicked on it which should bring up a page with a couple buttons.   But instead got an message about an error, not much details.  So I enabled debugging and it was the same file and same line number.  Ah, I for got the `this->` part so now I fix it to read `$this->sqlconn->close();`.  Again, deactivate, delete, install the plugin, confirm new files are in the `wp-content` folder, yet every time tells me line `123` has a `syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)`.

So now I know it must be using a cached copy somehow, to prove it I put a comment on line 123, went through reinstalling it, and sure enough same error on line `123`.  Tried updating the version number on the plugin, nope, same old error even though the correct new version shows in the plugins section.

Next I got the wp-cli and ran the command `wp cache flush` and that same message shows up on the command line.  I guess what I really want to do is `purge` the cache somehow.   I see a `wp cache delete <key> [<group>]` is available but I have no clue what any key or group would be.

So I'm stuck, how can I get it to see the new file.  There must be something cached somewhere.  I checked wp-super-cache and that is off/disabled.

Any WordPress plugin developers have some tips and solutions?

Thanks!!

Comment: It will be hard for everyone to debug invisible code. :)

Comment: The code didn't matter as I commented it out.  But I found it by accident, I renamed the file and it started working.  Then when stumbling around I saw in the root of the website it had copied the file there so it ended up using that instead of the one in the plugin folders.